# How to make the "In" operator in Mysql binary?

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, match

Suppose I have a statement like the following

```
select * from table where column in (select other_column from other_table)
```

but I would like this to match only when column "binary" equals other_column. Sort of like "binary like" but for the "in" operator.

I hope the question is clear.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select * from table where BINARY column in (select other_column from other_table)
```

or

```
select * from table where column in (select BINARY other_column from other_table)
```

But the performance of both of those will be awful because you're asking mysql to do a type conversion on all values before it can compare.

It's better to re-write the query as a JOIN as another comment suggested, but then you still have the issue of joining on a value that you're doing a type conversion on, and you can't use an index.

Better than that is if you want case sensitive or exact comparisons on this field, then change the charset in the table to BINARY for the columns, or use a collation with _cs

As usual the manual will tell you all of this [MySQL Character sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> Returns `1` if ***`expr`*** is equal to any of the values in the `IN` list, else returns `0`. If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type of ***`expr`*** and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a binary search. This means `IN` is very quick if the `IN` value list consists entirely of constants. Otherwise, type conversion takes place according to the rules described in [Section 12.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html), but applied to all the arguments.

Of course, in your example one could always replace `IN` with a join:

```
SELECT * FROM table JOIN other_table ON table.column = other_table.other_column
```